# German dialect translation

Tags: meaning, dialect

> "Lot dat sien!"
>
> "Ich joh sunset runner!"

Any idea what this means, it is in a German dialect.
I have tried many translation programs with no success.
This appears in a WWII diary written by a German soldier during the occupation of Poland.

Comment: Is this how you saw it written or did you transcribe by ear?

Comment: Even if I am bavarian, I can see that this must be _Plattdeutsch_ which is spoken in the high north of Germany. The 1st one I am pretty sure means _"Lass das sein!"_ ("Stop doing that!"). I am not a 100% sure about the 2nd one.

Comment: "runner" means "runter".

Comment: My impression was "Los das sehen" for the first, i.e. "check this out". For the second, I thought it is English :-), which is quite unlikely.

Comment: "sunset" probably means "sonst".

Comment: Can you give more text from the diary? Perhaps upload  a photo?

Comment: Einem der 1MG-Turmleute wird die Zeit zu lang und er macht sich am 1MG zu schaffen. Er schiebt es hin und her und will sich auch wohl überzeugen, ob alles in Ordnung ist. Dem anderen Mann wird die Sache ungeheuerlich, er befürchtet, dass der Kamerad Unheil anrichtet. Er ermahnt seinen Kameraden, die finger vom 1MG zu lassen.  Als alles Zureden nicht hilft, ruft er laut durch die Nacht "Lot dat sien!" "Ich joh sunset runner!"  Seine im Dialekt gesprochene Drohung hatte Erfolg. Am nächsten Tag hatte er den weiteren Erfolg, dass die ganze Kompanie lacht.

Answer (score 8):

This is Plattdeutsch. There are several dialects of that language.

*Lot dat sien!* Translates to 
Lass das sein! - *Stop it*

*Ich joh sunset runner*
This is hard to translate for me. I don't recognize *sunset* as a platt word, at least in my dialect. Also *ich* would be *ik* in most parts. Anyway *ich joh runner* could mean *ich gehe runter* - *I go down* in the sense of I go down to the river, the bar or something of the like.

Comment: "Ich joh sunset runner" probably means "Ich geh sonst runter". I don't think it means "Ich gehe sonst unter" (in the river), but something like leaving a place above ground level (perhaps a ladder).

Comment: @PaulFrost I'm not sure if you maybe assumed that Karlokick wrote *I go down **in** the river*, so I just wanted to point out that he wrote ***to** the river*

Comment: @amadeusamadeus I agree, I misunderstood it.

Comment: Are you able to narrow down the area from which that Platt may come? My uninformed guess would be somewhere south of the Baltic Sea rather than the North Sea based especially on the /o/ vowels in there but I can’t say I have the deepest understanding.

Answer (score 3):

At least the vowels sound familiar in Swiss German:

> Loss das sii
>
> Ich go (ga,gang) ...

"runner" must be "runter" is "hinunter" (in this case). This is "abe" in Swiss.

"sunset" could mean "sowieso", but maybe I am guessing from context.

> I ga **sunsch einewäg** abe
>
> Ich geh' **sonst sowieso** runter

I go *otherwise* down there *anyway*

(but in German this duplication is often used)

According to this theory, "sunset" would be a special short form of "sonst sowieso".